# Why cleanup useEffect function called at first render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

here is Sidemenu/mobile menu Component

```
import React, { useContext, useRef } from "react";
import useMenu from "../Hooks/useMenu";
import { Context } from "../context/SideMenuContext";
import { StyledSideMenu } from "./StyledComponent/StyledSideMenu";
import Button from "./Button";
import useOnClickOutside from "../Hooks/useOnClickOutside";
import Hamburger from "./Hamburger";
function SideMenu() {
  const { IsOpen, setIsOpen } = useContext(Context);
  const wrapperref = useRef();
  const items = useMenu();
  useOnClickOutside(wrapperref, () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  });
  return (
    <StyledSideMenu ref={wrapperref} IsOpen={IsOpen}>
      <Hamburger />
      {items}
      <Button padding="5% 10%">Resume</Button>
    </StyledSideMenu>
  );
}
export default SideMenu;
```

Here is useOnClickOutside Hooks.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
function useOnClickOutside(ref, handler) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (event) => {
      if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        return;
      }
      handler();
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener);
      document.removeEventListener("touchstart", listener);
      console.log("cleaned up");
    };
  }, [ref, handler]);
}

export default useOnClickOutside;
```

Why useEffect function called at first render? when Sidemenu/mobile menu component still didn't unmount from DOM,even it's never unmount from dom ,it's only being width zero. But we know clean up only happened when component unmount from dom. I didn't post this question only for getting solution, i went to know the reason or react priciple for this behavior. Pls explain it in details as far as you can.

NB: My app not wrapped with **StrictMode**.

Comment: Your useEffect has two dependencies, so it doesn't only run on mount/unmount, it runs everytime either of the dependencies change.

Comment: Additionally: the function you're passing as `handler` is not memoised, so it changes each time the `SideMenu` is rendered, which will cause the cleanup to be called before `useEffect` is run with the new handler.

Comment: Additionally, using variable from `useRef` hook (wrapperref) in depsArray of useEffect (or any other hook) will not work. React will not detect the changes of it so no rerenders or useEffect/useCallback/useMemo reexecutions.

Comment: @pilchard but how dependency/handler function getting change when i click Hamburger menu icon everytime?

Comment: I assume Hamburger triggers a render which as @motto noted re-calls `useOnClickOutside` with a new anonymous handler